# Template type deduction not working in C++

Tags: c++

I have two templates.

The first one for an integer

```
template <class T>
T myMin(T a, T b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

The second one for a string

```
template <class TypeFrom, class TypeTo>
TypeTo convert(TypeFrom &from)
{
    return static_cast<TypeTo>(from);
}

template <>
std::string convert<std::wstring, std::string>(std::wstring &from)
{
    return std::string(from.begin(), from.end());
}
```

The first template I can use without using the types

```
int c = myMin(1,2);
```

But for the second template I have to use the types

```
std::string  st = convert<std::wstring, std::string>(sw);
```

I can not use it without:

```
std::string  st = convert(sw);  // this fails with the error "no accordance found for convet<TypeFrom, TypeTo>(wstring)"
```

Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template argument cannot be deduced from return type of a function. You could swap the order of your template parameter to be able to do type deduction of the input argument(s):

```
template <class TypeTo, class TypeFrom >
TypeTo convert(TypeFrom &from)
{
    return static_cast<TypeTo>(from);
}

template <>
std::string convert<std::string, std::wstring>(std::wstring &from)
{
    return std::string(from.begin(), from.end());
}

// Partial deduction
std::string st = convert<std::string>(sw);
```

Basically, you cannot do `convert(sw)` because it may be ambiguous in many cases, e.g.:

```
// Call without using the return value
convert(sw);

// Call with return value sent to an overloaded function
void g (std::string) ;
void g (int) ;
g(convert(sw));
```

AFAIK, the same restriction applies to overloaded function (for the same reason). You cannot have in `C++` (and in many languages such as Java), the following:

```
int f ();
float f ();
```

Actually, if you think about it, even your call is ambiguous because `std::string` has multiple constructors, so should I do:

```
std::string st = convert <std::string> (sw) ; // Copy constructor
std::string st = convert <const char *> (sw) ; // Constructor from const char *
```

The main idea is that while it may not be ambiguous for you (while would I convert to `const char *` instead of directly `std::string`?), it is ambiguous for the compiler, and it is not the compiler role to make that kind of choices.

Comment: I see! Thank's. That means I should skip the =operator and use the return-type/value as an other parameter.

Comment: There is always `auto` (in C++11): `auto st = convert<std::string>(sw);`.

Comment: Is there a good reason why Bjarne Stroustrup don't considered the return type for the function deduction?

Comment: @NECIP You should ask him ;) More seriously, note that you cannot overload a function by its returning type (`float f()` and `int f()` is not possible in C++ or even Java, AFAIK). The restriction might be explained by the fact that a call to `f()` would be ambiguous in many cases (`f();` alone, `g(f())` is `g` as overload for `float` and `int`, and so on... ).

Comment: @NECIP See my updated answer to have more readable information about why (IMO) you cannot do that.

Comment: Thank you Holt! ^^ In some constellations the function might be ambiguous, but if I consider both sides of the = operator I have a unique combination of types! We should write a petition to Bjarne to consider this lack in his next upgrade of C++ or he should gave us the possibility to expand the functionality of C++ in ower own image... ^^